# How to stub 2nd call of method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

With MS Fakes, is there a way to supply a method body for the first call of a stubbed method and supply a different method body for the 2nd call of the same method?

I'm testing a method that calls classA.MyMethod() twice.  I've stubbed classA.MyMethod() in my unit test.  But this means both calls to MyMethod() will return the same thing.

I'd like the stubbed method to do this:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
  var result1 = classA.MyMethod(); //return null
  ...
  var result2 = classA.MyMethod(); //return x
}
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Microsoft Fakes, but other frameworks I've worked with (e.g. Rhino Mocks) allow you to do things like `.Return.Once()` to specify how many times you want that results returned. You can have two `.Return.Once()` statements to achieve the desired effect. If this framework doesn't have that, that'd be rather limiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the shim within the method call to replace it after the first one is complete:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        Something.Fakes.ShimClassA.MethodA = () =>
        {
            Something.Fakes.ShimClassA.MethodA = () =>
            {
                return "Second";
            };
            return "first";
        };
        var f = Something.ClassA.MethodA();      // first
        var s = Something.ClassA.MethodA();      // second
        var t = Something.ClassA.MethodA();      // second
    }

    var orig = Something.ClassA.MethodA();      // This will use the original implementation of MethodA

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain how that logic works?  Does it start with the outer part and ordinally work its way in?  So if I want a third return, I nest it inside the "Second" block?