# C# Multiple Stub implementation for method with T

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Currently I have a factory class where I have method to instantiate different classes using reflection and return a base interface which all classes implement. The code works fine in general. But when I turned to write unit test (ms-test) on the class I'm running into issues when I try to instantiate multiple classes

Factory class:

```
public class BusinessFactory : IBusinessFactory
{
        public BusinessFactory()
        {
        }

        public IBaseBusiness Create<T>() where T : class
        {
            return (IBaseBusiness) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        }
}
```

Unit test:

I tried to stub the `IBusinessFactory` and inject into my class under test so I can fake the implementations that the class uses.

Example: failing to complete TestInit method, and it's failing when instantiating stub of class2.

```
interface IClass1 : IBaseBusiness{}

public Class1 : IClass1{}

interface IClass2 : IBaseBusiness{}

public Class2 : IClass2{}

public TestFactory{

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit()
{
    var fkBusFac = new StubIBusinessFactory();

    fkBusFac.CreateOf1<Class1>(() => new StubIClass1() { });
    fkBusFac.CreateOf1<Class2>(() => new StubIClass2() { });
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What are "issues" and "failing to complete"? Is there an error message? PS I assume you're using microsoft fakes, you might want to add that as a tag to your question. PS this might be a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159248/how-to-stub-2nd-call-of-method

Comment: Is initialization working if you leave only Class1.

Comment: What is StubIBusinessFactory?

Comment: Also, do you really need to 2 initializations in TestInitialize? Often you should move one initialization to UT_imtestingsomefeature and second initialization to UT_imtestingSomeOtherStuff

Comment: @zxxc StubIBusinessFactory is generated by msfakes. Yes it works if only class1 is there. multiple tests uses the TestInitialize method in which cases the TestInitialize method is ran for each seperately.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Issue is The test class its failing at runtime telling that unable to create Fake implementation for Class 2. Failing to Complete- I mean the code is failing at the point where fake class 2 is created

Comment: So split into 2 testclasses

Comment: @zxxc for example if there is class that is using the factory(under test) has dependency on both Class1,2 then i cant split.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157669/discussion-between-krishna-and-zxxc).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but...

What happens if I do the following?:

```
var business = Create<string>();
```

You have absolutely no type safety at all here. If the created object implements `IBaseBusiness`, ensure it does and simply call `new()` (oh, and if its a factory method, shouldn't you be making it static?):

```
public static IBaseBusiness Create<T>() where T : IBaseBunsiness, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the Type safety and being static method. i will make those changes.

Comment: If there are any parameters for T , i dont think just new T() with work, right?

Comment: in case of parameters you should Activator

Comment: @Krishna yes, if you have constructors with parameters then obviously `new()` won’t do, I simply showed you the option based on the code shown in your question. You can get around this problem using `Activator` although it’s less type safe (but still considerably better than your current solution).